# How to get current Entity detail using Dynamics CRM plugins in RetrieveMultiple message?

Tags: c#, plugins, microsoft-dynamics

I've added a plugin at `RetrieveMultiple`message of one of custom entity. Now, the subgrid of that custom entity is placed on `Accounts` as well as on `Contacts`. Now I want this plugin to do below:

1. Execute on Contacts
2. Restrict plugin to execute on Accounts
3. Retrieve context of Contacts

Below is my source code:
`if (context.MessageName.Equals("RetrieveMultiple"))`
`{`
  `Guid budgetID = (Guid)context.PrimaryEntityId;`
`}`

Above source code return no guid. As it is running in RetrieveMultiple context. How is it possible to get the entity context?

Comment: A RetrieveMultiple plugin is definitely not the way you want to approach this. You want to add context specific filters to a single execution of a query, while a RetrieveMultiple plugin provides non-context specific ability to add filters to all queries against an entity. What you are trying to do requires custom form elements or client side scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In general, it is not recommended to register plug-ins for these
>   messages due to the risks associated with slowing down the requests to
>   return an entity record or records from various entry points.

Here is official documentation which provides more light on it. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/best-practices/business-logic/limit-registration-plugins-retrieve-retrievemultiple#guidance)

Now you wish to get Guid of Contact from this retreivemultiple message, This is not possible reason RetreiveMultiple works independent from any parent or associated entiy, One more example as  retreivemultiple run on Views as well and how will you find any Guid of Contact or so on from View. Hence You will not Guid.

If you register your plugin as retrievemultiple  for custom entity, it will not respect from which entity you have your gird, same reason as above. Hence you will not be able to restrict it based on other entity.

I would rather suggest you try different way achieving your desired req.
Maybe JS could come handy to you depending on what you wish to achieve.

**Another way using RetreiveMultiple**

When you use RetreiveMultiple and debug your plugin, you will get FetchxmlExpression query i.e CRM returns data based on query. When you convert this query to queryexpression you will see different query.

For Ex: If you custom entity is 1:N or N:1 related with account or contact then in your query you will have something like
Select * from customentity where accountid="abcd"
or
Select * from customentity where contact="abcd"

If you have N:N relation then your query will add link entity to it rather than direct filter as above.

Now you can decide whether query is of you intrest i.e account or contact if yes
you can get guid from either filter or linked based on your relation and then change your fetchxml query to show only relevant record if not let the query go as it is.

Similarly if you did not find query coming from any record then let go the query as it is.

But all this above process needs some debugging and multiple call to server.

Also w.r.t Js mentioned in comment take a look at below thread may be it will help you out.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/307291/is-there-a-supported-method-to-filter-subgrid-based-on-a-main-form-lookup-v9-online

Comment: My requirements is to add custom filter on subgrid, through JS it is unsupported.

Comment: NoI do not think it is not unsupported, you can do so with JS.
You mean if you have 10 records you only wish to show some 6-7 Records depending on your criteria?
Are you using Unified Interface?

Comment: Yes, like if I've project lookup on contacts form then I need to filter only those records that are related to selected lookup. 

No, I am using classical interface in on-prem environment

Comment: then you can definitely use Js to achieve your req.

Comment: I know that, it works only in legacy forms not in Turbo forms.